# Получить html-данные по клику на элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('input:not(:first)').click(function() {
  var element1 = $('span').html();
  console.log(element1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <input id="1" type="radio" name="example"><label for="1">number one <span>50.1</span></label>
  <input id="2" type="radio" name="example"><label for="2">number two <span>100.5</span></label>
  <input id="3" type="radio" name="example"><label for="3">number three <span>200.9</span></label>
</form>
```

Предполагаю, что это все должно быть связано с this

Comment: Добрый вечер. Да, используйте this

Comment: @ slo_nik вопрос - как?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем случае `HTML` идет после инпута, поэтому, сначала получим следующий после инпута элемент (метод `next()`), потом достанем его деток (метод `children()`), а потом достанем `HTML`:

```js
$('input:not(:first)').click(function() {
  var element1 = $(this).next().children().html();
  console.log(element1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <input id="1" type="radio" name="example"><label for="1">number one <span>50.1</span></label>
  <input id="2" type="radio" name="example"><label for="2">number two <span>100.5</span></label>
  <input id="3" type="radio" name="example"><label for="3">number three <span>200.9</span></label>
</form>
```

Comment: нет, нужно содержимое <span>

Comment: ну так сразу и надо было писать )))) внес правку в ответ, смотрите

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Одним словом, в таких случаях нужно применять функции перемещения по DOM